# ¿Cómo crear una tabla temporal en SQL Server dentro de un cursor con variables?

Tags: sql-server

Estoy trabajando con un cursor, en dónde quiero mostrar cierta información de mi base de datos, así como también hago uso de declaración de variables que formarán parte de mi cursor.

Adjunto mi código del cursor y la declaración de las variables:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempLineas

DECLARE @LINEA_SELEC VARCHAR(70)
DECLARE @TOTAL_MES DECIMAL(30,2)
DECLARE @TOTAL_MES_ANT DECIMAL(30,2)

SELECT [LINEANIVEL3] --AS NIVEL_SELECCIONADO
INTO #TempLineas
FROM [OPEX].[dbo].[PRUEBAOPEX]
WHERE MONTH(FECHA) IN( 1 , 2)
GROUP BY [LINEANIVEL3]

DECLARE C_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
SELECT LINEANIVEL3 FROM #TempLineas

OPEN C_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM C_CURSOR INTO @LINEA_SELEC
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @TOTAL_MES_ANT = (SELECT (SUM([MONTODEBITO]) - SUM([MONTOCREDITO])) FROM [OPEX].[dbo].[PRUEBAOPEX]  WHERE LINEANIVEL3 = @LINEA_SELEC AND MONTH(FECHA) = 2 - 1) 
SET @TOTAL_MES = (SELECT (SUM([MONTODEBITO]) - SUM([MONTOCREDITO])) FROM [OPEX].[dbo].[PRUEBAOPEX]  WHERE LINEANIVEL3 = @LINEA_SELEC AND MONTH(FECHA) = 2) 

SELECT  @LINEA_SELEC AS LINEA, 
        ISNULL(@TOTAL_MES_ANT, 0) AS MES_ANTERIOR,
        ISNULL(@TOTAL_MES, 0) AS MES_ACTUAL, 
       (ISNULL(@TOTAL_MES_ANT, 0) - ISNULL(@TOTAL_MES, 0)) AS DIFERENCIA

FETCH NEXT FROM C_CURSOR INTO @LINEA_SELEC
END

CLOSE C_CURSOR

DEALLOCATE C_CURSOR
```

El cursor me retorna todos los registros, cada uno por aparte.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo quisiera saber es si podría estos registros agruparlos dentro de una tabla temporal, o existe alguna manera más eficiente de hacerlo, lo que yo busco mostrar es como este ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberme dado a entender, y agradezco la posible ayuda recibida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es eliminar el cursor por completo y simplemente usar una sola consulta usando GROUP BY.

```
DECLARE @MES_ANTERIOR DATE = DATEADD( MM, DATEDIFF( MM, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0),
        @MES_ACTUAL   DATE = DATEADD( MM, DATEDIFF( MM, -1, GETDATE()), -1);

WITH ctePRUEVAOPEX AS(
    SELECT  LINEANIVEL3 AS LINEA,
            SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(FECHA) = MONTH( @MES_ANTERIOR) THEN ISNULL( [MONTODEBITO], 0) - ISNULL( [MONTOCREDITO], 0) END) AS MES_ANTERIOR,
            SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(FECHA) = MONTH( @MES_ACTUAL) THEN ISNULL( [MONTODEBITO], 0) - ISNULL( [MONTOCREDITO], 0) END) AS MES_ACTUAL
    FROM [OPEX].[dbo].[PRUEBAOPEX]  
    WHERE FECHA BETWEEN @MES_ANTERIOR AND @MES_ACTUAL
    GROUP BY LINEANIVEL3
)
SELECT  LINEA,
        MES_ANTERIOR,
        MES_ACTUAL,
        MES_ANTERIOR - MES_ACTUAL AS DIFERENCIA
FROM ctePRUEVAOPEX;
```

También incluí los cálculos para las fechas del inicio del mes anterior y el fin del mes actual.

Comment: Hola, agradezco tu respuesta. Fíjate que la sintaxis es incorrecta, exactamente en el cierre de parentesís de los CASE. En dónde quiero mostrar el mes anterior y actual.

Comment: Me faltó el `END` de los `CASE`. Pero ya está corregido el código.